# PostgreSQL: Creating a CHECK CONSTRAINT for personal number

Tags: postgresql

I have a task in my school to create a database. In this DB I have to create a table that called person that has the some attributes (country, personalnumber, name etc.).

When creating the DB I have to make sure that the personal number should have the following format: `XXXXXXXX-XXXX` where `X` is a digit between 0 and 9.

I have tried to do it as following:

```
ALTER TABLE person 
   ADD CONSTRAINT persondigits CHECK
      (personalNumber LIKE '________-____' ) 
      AND personalnumber IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','-')
```

where `personalnumber` type is `varchar`, but this is not working.
I have tried many other `CHECK`s but still not working.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe  thank for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you can use [SIMILAR TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) pattern like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
personal_number CHAR(13) CHECK (personal_number SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{4}')
);
```

Comment: Ohhh AWESOME it works .. Thank you very much (Y) .. i did not know about SIMILAR TO ... thank u again

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`SIMILAR TO` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) or the `~` operator with a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in your `CHECK` constraint.